# facebook SSO not working

Tags: android, facebook

I wanted to use facebook SSO in my android application.I have downloaded samples from https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started/facebook-sdk-for-android/ . I ran HelloFacebookSample example It launched the facebook app to login and after successful login I was able to "pick some friends" and "post status" It worked for the first time only after that it is showing error message inside fb window.

"The page you requested cannot be displayed right now.It may be temporarily unavailable, the link you clicked on may be broken or expired or may not have permission to view this page."

No idea what is wrong and how to get SSO work?

Comment: Did you get any answer or solution for this. I am also facing the same problem. Can you please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

I'm investigating this problem, and while I can't find a clear repro case, the solution/workaround is to go into Settings > App Settings (Application Manager or similar) > Facebook > Clear Data.

This obviously is not clear to end users and I have no idea how to deal with it programmatically.

For the record, we've observed this problem

- when tapping an invitation notification ("Some Person invited you to try SomeApp")
- when logging out and (attempting to) log back in via FB

Now that I've cleared the data from the one device I had that was doing this, I cannot reproduce it anymore. This is very frustrating.